# Java Adding and Subtracting of Time

Tags: java

I have four dates and I wanted to get the total...

**EXAMPLE**

timeInAM=9:00

timeOutAM=12:00

timeInPM=13:00

timeOutPM=18:00

I wanted to make `total=(timeOutAM-timeInAM)+(timeOutPM-timeInPM)` that would result in total=8:00

but it gives me '16:00:00'

Here's what I did:
**DATE**

```
SimpleDateFormat tf24=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date timeInAM=new Date();
Date timeOutAM=new Date();
Date timeInPM=new Date();
Date timeOutPM=new Date();
long total;

timeInAM=tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
timeOutAM=tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
timeInPM=tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
timeOutPM=tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
total=(timeOutAM.getTime()-timeInAM.getTime())+(timeOutPM.getTime()-timeInPM.getTime());
System.out.println(tf24.format(new Date(total)));
```

**CALENDAR**

```
Calendar timeInAM=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar timeOutAM=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar timeInPM=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar timeOutPM=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar total=Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat tf24=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

timeInAM.setTime(tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString()));
timeOutAM.setTime(tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()));
timeInPM.setTime(tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString()));
timeOutPM.setTime(tf24.parse(tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 4).toString()));
long sum=(timeOutAM.getTimeInMillis()-timeInAM.getTimeInMillis())+(timeOutPM.getTimeInMillis()-timeInPM.getTimeInMillis());
total.setTimeInMillis(sum);
System.out.println("total : "+tf24.format(total.getTime()));
```

Comment: Format your total time using your SimpleDateFormat

Comment: but it gives me the wrong computation the result should be 8:00 not 16:00

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Try specifying the time zone (everywhere, ideally) as UTC.

Comment: Why the Calendar indirection (opposed to just working with the Date instances you get from parse())?

Comment: Have you added any breakpoints or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try to [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) library (if you can use other libraries). With the following you can achieve what you need by calling [`LocalTime::minusHours`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#minusHours-int-) and similar commands:

```
LocalTime timeInAM=new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);
LocalTime timeOutAM=new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);
LocalTime timeInPM=new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);
LocalTime timeOutPM=new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);

LocalTime amInterval = timeOutAM.minusHours(timeInAM.getHourOfDay()).minusMinutes(timeInAM.getMinuteOfHour());
LocalTime pmInterval = timeOutPM.minusHours(timeInPM.getHourOfDay()).minusMinutes(timeInPM.getMinuteOfHour());

LocalTime total = pmInterval.plusHours(amInterval.getHourOfDay()).plusMinutes(amInterval.getMinuteOfHour());
```

Use a proper **DateTimeFormatter** to parse/print the dates in **LocalTime**.

Comment: what is hoursOfDay? long?

Comment: The hoursOfDay is a _int_ representing the hour of the **LocalTime** ([reference](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#getHourOfDay())). If you want a LocalTime representing "2:30", use `new LocalTime(2,30)`

Comment: I imported joda-time-2.6.jar in my project but the '.minusHours' does not appear

Comment: @askManiac I edited the Answer to [link to doc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#minusHours-int-) to prove the method exists. You must be having a Java problem, something with the IDE or class path or such; try clean-and-build in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but here:

You can try to use:

```
double timeInAMint = Double.parseDouble(timeInAM);
double timeOutAMint = Double.parseDouble(timeoutAM);
double timeInPMint = Double.parseDouble(timeInPM);
double timeOutPMint = Double.parseDouble(timeOutPM);
double sum = timeInAMint + timeOutAMint + timeInPMint + timeOutPMint;
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: I don't think that would help since were dealing with time? 

so what if timeinam is 12:59 and I added 1:52

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance.

Edit : Sample implementation.

```
Calendar timeInBeforeBreak = Calendar.getInstance();
timeInBeforeBreak.clear();

Calendar timeOutBeforeBreak = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOutBeforeBreak.clear();

timeInBeforeBreak.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
timeInBeforeBreak.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
timeOutBeforeBreak.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
timeOutBeforeBreak.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

long timeMillis = timeOutBeforeBreak.getTimeInMillis() - timeInBeforeBreak.getTimeInMillis();

System.out.println("Hours :"+timeMillis/1000/60/60);
```

Comment: I tried using dates and Calendar but it gives me the wrong computation

Comment: Ok I've eddited the post :)

Comment: Edited post to included a sample calculation as well !

Comment: i used your formula timemillis/1000/60/60 and it works fine for whole numbers what if the time is

6:30-12:00 and 13:00-18:00 the result should be 7:30 but it gives 7 only

Comment: Use modulus. Eg: System.out.println("Time in minutes :"+(timeMillis/1000/60) % 60);